# NOT NULL constraint failed: cms_viewcount.session

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to get users ip address for a blog project view counts, and when the user isn't logged in a get this error

```
integrityError at /article/another-post-to-test-things-out/
NOT NULL constraint failed: cms_viewcount.session
```

Here is my views.py

```
# regular blog details
def blog_detail(request, slug):
    template_name = 'cms/single.html'
    blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    msg = False
    form = CommentForm()
    
    ip=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    if not ViewCount.objects.filter(blogview=blog, session=request.session.session_key):
        view=ViewCount(blogview=blog, ip_address=ip, session=request.session.session_key)
        
        view.save()
    blog_views=ViewCount.objects.filter(blogview=blog).count()
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user

        if blog.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            msg = True
    context = {'blog': blog, 'msg':msg, 'form':form, "view_count":blog_views,}

    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.blog = blog
            comment.owner = request.user
            comment.save()


            messages.success(request, 'Your review was successfully submitted!')
            return redirect('blog-detail', slug=blog.slug)
    
        if not request.user or not request.user.is_authenticated:
            
            return render(request, template_name, context)

        else:
            return render(request, template_name, context)
    except:
        return render(request, "cms/login-prompt.html", context)
```

Here is the error on my browser also

```
  view.save() …
Local vars
Variable    Value
blog    
<Blog: Another Post to test things out>
form    
<CommentForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(body)>

msg 
False
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/article/another-post-to-test-things-out/'>
slug    
'another-post-to-test-things-out'
template_name   
'cms/single.html'
view    
<ViewCount:>
```

PLease how can I fix this error , note everthing works fine when the user is logged in

models.py

```
#views count models
class ViewCount(models.Model):
    blogview=models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name="view_count", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    session=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ip_address)
    
    #comment model
    class Comment(models.Model):
        owner= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        blog= models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True,editable=False)
        
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created']
        
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.blog)
```

forms.py if need be

```
#comment form
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body']

        labels = {
            'body': 'Add a comment'
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

Here is the error again

```
IntegrityError at /article/another-post-to-test-things-out/
NOT NULL constraint failed: cms_viewcount.session
```

Comment: You already have the User's IP with `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`, but if a user isn't logged in they won't have a session and a session_key.. So you either need to set that `session` field blank/null=true or not add a view count if the Person isn't logged it.

Comment: Wow, thanks didn't thought of this, so how can I get a view count for a user that's not logged in?

Comment: You'd just set the field to blank/null=True, and if that field is empty you know it was an anon user. Also: From my understanding you can't give an Anon User a session, that session_key is directly related to them being logged in

Comment: Oh okay, that's true, you are right, but if I log out and log in back, the views count increases, I don't want that, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the required session argument in this line:

```
view=ViewCount(blogview=blog, ip_address=ip, session=request.session.session_key)
```

Since the user isn't logged in, the value is Null.

Allow the value to be Null:

```
`session=models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True)`
```

Or generate a session for an anonymous user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added null = True but have some questions, what do you mean by not passing the right argument for the session on the view please? , Secondly how can I generate session for anonymous user?